# Rendering Datatable from callback function - Dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard with multiple tabs and each tab triggers and .py file that renders different elements of plotly objects.

For instance, my callback functions return plots, charts and I am looking to return Datatable.

I am able to do render pandas dataframe with go.Table as shown in the example, but not with DataTable, which is newer and offers an enhanced user experience.

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import dash_table
import flask
from datetime import datetime as dt
from app import app


layout = html.Div([

    html.Div([

        dcc.Dropdown(
                id='select',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in List],
                value='abc',
                placeholder="xyz",
                style={'width': '100%'}

        ), 

    ], style={"width": "15%", "margin-left": "20%", "margin-right": "35%"}), 


    html.Div([

        dash_table.DataTable(

            id='my-table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_lease.columns],

        )
    ])
])


@app.callback(Output('my-table', 'data'),
              [
                  Input("landlord-select", "value")
              ]
             )
def render_table(company, market):

    df_sub1 = df_lease[(df_lease['Landlord'] == company)] 

    df_sub1 = df_sub1[['UnitNo',
                       'Commencement_Date',
                       'Expiration_Date'
                       ]]

    return df_sub1.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Expected behavior is to render the pandas dataframe as DataTable.

File structure:

```
- app.py
- index.py
- apps
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- app1.py
   |-- app2.py
```

index.py includes all the code that renders multi-page/tab layout, and the children property of `dcc.Tabs` is updated as layout object from template file (app1.py) is passed. This is where, I believe, the error is generated from.

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # tabs
    html.Div([

        dcc.Tabs(
            id="tabs",
            style={"height":"60","verticalAlign":"middle"},
            children=[
                 dcc.Tab(label="Marketing", value="marketing_tab"),
                 dcc.Tab(label="Tenants", value="tenants_tab"),
                 dcc.Tab(label="Portfolio", value="portfolio_tab"),
            ],
            value="marketing_tab",
        )

        ],

        className="row tabs_div"
        ),

        # Tab content
        html.Div(id="tab_content", style={"margin": "2% 3%"})

])

@app.callback(Output("tab_content", "children"),
          [
              Input("tabs", "value")
          ]
         )
def render_content(tab):
    """
    For user selections, return the relevant tab
    """
    if tab == "marketing_tab":
        return marketing.layout
    elif tab == "tenants_tab":
        return tenants.layout
    elif tab == "portfolio_tab":
        return portfolio.layout
    else:
        return marketing.layout


    # In[10]:

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

[This link](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable) has some good examples for you to check out. Basically, you'll want your callback to update the `data` prop of the table. Something like this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('my-table', 'data'),
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def callback_a(i):
    df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.arange(30).reshape(5, 6))

    return df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

It's important that the columns for the table be defined so that the `id` for each column matches the column name in the dataframe. If you are changing the data in the table, then you may want another callback/output to update the `columns` prop as well.

Comment: Thanks. So, I attempted to updated the data property. However, I run into `InvalidCallbackReturnValue error. The callback for property children of component tab_content returned a value having type module which is not JSON serializable.` This could be because of my file structure and multi-page layout as I have pointed out in the question.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code, including as much of the imports and callback structure as possible? I'll take another look and see if I can help.

Comment: This link might help: https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/tabs. The layout is rendered as children property of dcc.Tabs.

Comment: @keval, the error is mentioning code not shown above. Is that coming from your other app? Would you be able to share that as well?

Comment: my guess is that the error is being generated from index.py file which has all the code for multi-page/tab layout. I'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks for that update. I cannot see what you've defined `marketing.layout` and the others as, but that's where the problem is coming from. If you update those return values to components, like content wrapped in `html.Div`, then the error should stop.

Comment: Thx. That fixed the error. However, I am still having trouble rendering DataTable. It's not throwing any error, but it isn't rendering any objects from `html.Div`. I am referring to the code at the top of my question where I update the data property of table.

Comment: The code was still throwing an error for me, because you have two args in the callback, but only one `Input`. When I removed the second arg, and used a dummy `df` for testing, and defined the `app.layout` as the `layout` from your first block of code, the app runs. Could it be that the `company` value you're searching for isn't present in your `df`? If I tell it to look for a value that isn't in my placeholder `df`, then it only shows the columns but no data.

Comment: Good catch. Interesting that worked for you. Did you have `index.py`, `app.py` and `template.py` files separate? The `children` property of tabs in `index.py` is updated with layout object from the template. Minimal reproducible code can be found here - https://github.com/plotly/dash-table/issues/472.

Comment: There is still not enough code to make this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The contents of `temp2` are not shown, and the code still has many syntax errors in the link you shared. I've also noticed that you're using `df_lease` to define the columns for the table. Where does that come from? It isn't defined anywhere. If that `df_lease` has columns that do not perfectly match up with `df` you create from the `read_csv` method, then that would also prevent the app from showing anything after the callback runs.

Comment: I see. I think, we can ignore `temp2` for this purpose. Sorry, `df_lease` was a typo from earlier code. It should be fixed now. The column names are pulled from the dataframe from read_csv statement.

Comment: `pip install dash==1.0.0` <-- Running this fixed the issue.